# Prove that $(ab+bc+ca)\left( \frac{a}{b(b+1)}+\frac{b}{c(c+1)}+\frac{c}{a(a+1)}\right)\ge \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Q: Prove that where $a,b,c \in [0,1]$, $a+b+c=1$
> $$(ab+bc+ca)\left( \frac{a}{b(b+1)}+\frac{b}{c(c+1)}+\frac{c}{a(a+1)}\right)\ge
>  \frac{3}{4}$$

My work: The first method tried was to use the arithmetic-geometric mean because of the positive number condition. However, the expression of the problem becomes more complicated, but the solution is not visible.

Comment: Have you tried using Cauchy-Schwartz on the numerators and denominators of the second parenthesized expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ is convex on $x > 0$ (note: $f''(x) = \frac{6x^2 + 6x + 2}{x^3(x+1)^3} > 0$).
Thus, by Jensen's inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{a}{b(b+1)}+\frac{b}{c(c+1)}+\frac{c}{a(a+1)} 
 &\ge f(ab + bc + ca)\\
 &= \frac{1}{(ab+bc+ca)(ab+bc+ca+1)}.
\end{align*}

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(ab+bc+ca)\left( \frac{a}{b(b+1)}+\frac{b}{c(c+1)}+\frac{c}{a(a+1)}\right)\\
 \ge{}& (ab+bc+ca)\cdot \frac{1}{(ab+bc+ca)(ab+bc+ca+1)}\\
 ={}& \frac{1}{ab+bc+ca+1}\\
 \ge{}& \frac{1}{1/3 + 1}\\
 ={}& \frac34
\end{align*}
where we have used $ab + bc + ca \le (a + b + c)^2/3 = 1/3$.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Because by Holder $$\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(b+1)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}a(b+1)\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(b+1)}}{ab+ac+bc+1}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{ab+ac+bc+1}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}+1}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: It is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: I just remembered that I saw this inequality before.
It is a problem of Gabiel Dospinescu.
I saw a proof by using integrals.

We have
$$\frac{a}{b(b+1)}+\frac{b}{c(c+1)}+\frac{c}{a(a+1)} 
= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{a}{(x+b)^2} + \frac{b}{(x+c)^2} + \frac{c}{(x+a)^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x. \tag{1}$$

By using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality twice, we have
$$\frac{a}{(x+b)^2} + \frac{b}{(x+c)^2} + \frac{c}{(x+a)^2}
\ge \frac{1}{(x + ab + bc + ca)^2}. \tag{2}$$
(Details are given at the end.)

From (1) and (2), we have
$$\frac{a}{b^2 + b} + \frac{b}{c^2 + c} + 
\frac{c}{a^2 + a} \ge \frac{1}{(ab + bc + ca)(ab + bc + ca + 1)}.$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{ab + bc + ca + 1} \ge \frac34$$
or
$$ab + bc + ca \le 1/3$$
which is true using $(a + b + c)^2 \ge 3(ab + bc + ca)$.

We are done.

---

*Details about (2)*:

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\left(\frac{a}{(x+b)^2} + \frac{b}{(x+c)^2} + \frac{c}{(x+a)^2}\right)(a + b + c)
\ge \left(\frac{a}{x + b} + \frac{b}{x + c} + \frac{c}{x + a}\right)^2$$
and
$$\frac{a}{x + b} + \frac{b}{x + c} + \frac{c}{x + a}
\ge \frac{(a + b + c)^2}{(ax + ab) + (bx + bc) + (cx + ca)} = \frac{1}{x + ab + bc + ca}.$$
(2) follows.